# Retornar DataHora Atualizada Android

Tags: java, android, classes

Fiz uma classe chamada DataHoraAtual contendo estes dados:

```
package com.projeto.projetov1.model;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DataHoraAtual {
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);
}
```

e na minha classe principal, quando o evento é criado tem este código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//aplica data hora atual do sistema no app
txtDataHoraOcorrencia = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.txtDataHoraOcorrencia);
DataHoraAtual dataHoraAtual = new DataHoraAtual();
txtDataHoraOcorrencia.setText(dataHoraAtual.toString());
}
```

Fazendo assim a data e hora não é exibida, mas aparece o seguinte:

> com.projeto.projetov1.model.DataHoraAtual@4f3b05b

mas se eu fizer assim, sem chamar a classe a data e hora aparece:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//aplica data hora atual do sistema no app
txtDataHoraOcorrencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDataHoraOcorrencia);
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String dateString = sdf.format(date);
txtDataHoraOcorrencia.setText(dataHoraAtual.toString());
}
```

o que estou fazendo errado?

Fazendo o procedimento que Valdeir sugeriu apresentou o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer que o método `toString()` retorne o valor de `dateString` tem de o sobrescrever:

```
public class DataHoraAtual {
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return dateString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Ramaral funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Não está funcionando, pois você está pegando o hash da classe.

Para seu código funcionar da maneira como você quer, é necessário chamar o valor do atributo **dateString**

Dessa forma:

```
txtDataHoraOcorrencia.setText(dataHoraAtual.dateString);
```

Comment: Valdeir, fiz o que sugeriu, mas não funcionou, editei a pergunta pra vc dar uma olhada... vlw

Comment: não funcionou porque você usou dataHoraAtual.dateString(),os 2 parenteses significa que está chamando um método e não um atributo.